# Passing a regex in a GET parameter?

Tags: regex, http, url

I have a RESTful API endpoint with a Mongo backend. I allow users to filter their queries using GET parameters, e.g. to get analytics for the `/about` page on the site:

```
/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath:/about
```

I would like to extend this to support regular expression filters, e.g. to get analytics for all pages below `/about` on the site:

```
/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath:/about/.*
```

What is the safest way to do this? Should I enclose the regex inside enclosing markers, and should I get users to pass URL escaped variables?

My requirements are as follows: firstly, I would like to write backend code to check that we have a valid regex before passing it on to my database. Secondly, I don't want the regexes passed in by users to get messed up by URL escaping.

One example of a problem: I initially started by enclosing all my regexes in slashes, like `/^about/.*$/`, but that doesn't work well because my server removes trailing slashes from URLs.

If anyone has any tips, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: This sounds like a very over the top design... surely 99.9% of the time, users will just want to search for the "regex": `.*keyword.*`. Also, what framework is your website using? - Have you looked into existing (similar) solutions?

Comment: I'm adding a search for two scenarios: (1) give me results for all paths beginning `/about`, and (2) give me all results for all paths matching a set of 10-20 strings. Regexes seem to be the best way to support this.

Comment: As for the second half of your question, the site isn't using a framework - I wish it was, but it's a hand-crafted set of Python scripts that I've inherited.

Comment: Ah, well that's unfortunate! :) Even so, it sounds like your solution (a generic regex) is far more complex than the problem you actually need to solve here. Why not just pass in a set of delimited params, and perform a generic /param1|param2|param3.../ regex behind the scenes?

Comment: In other words, something along the lines of: `/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath&topLevel=about&subLevelContains=users;books;clothes;...`. You then perform a generic regex with the `subLevelContains` param.

Comment: What do you mean by `messed up by URL escaping`? As long as you escape/unescape properly, the original text should be retained without issue. That said, if that's not going to work for you, I'd consider base64 encoding the regex using Javascript and then decoding it on the back end with Python.